# how to choose a "sub-array" in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of arrays

```
$person = array(2) {
      [billy]=>
        array(3) {
          ["height"]=>
          string(60) "tall"
          ["build"]=>
          string(7) "slim"
         ["attractiveness"]=>
         string(7) "extremely"
      }
    [carl]=>
      array(3) {
        ["height"]=>
        string(60) "short"
        ["build"]=>
        string(7) "chubby"
        ["attractiveness"]=>
        string(7) "neglegible"
   }
```

Unfortunately for Carl, there just isn't any interest in him. Billy conversely is extremely in demand, and people would like to see Billy's details out and about.

So I want to loop through the array and return only Billy's information.

```
function findHotty($billy){
   foreach ( $person as $meat)
   {
      // wizardry 
      return onlyBilly
   }
}
```

I was hoping to pass the name of the subarray in the function, so if tomorrow Carl is all the rage - he has a certain undeniable charm -  when I call the method I can pass it Carl and it looks for his sub-array.
I hope that's clear!

Comment: have you ever programmed in PHP? because this is PHP 101 coding

Comment: `return $person[$name]` - no need for any looping, although you should implement some kind of error checking to ensure that the name exists in the persons array.

Comment: In addition this is not PHP array syntax.

Comment: everyone struggles with the basics from time to time!

Comment: @sємsєм this is PHP `var_dump` of an array.

Comment: @Jurik I didn't fancy writing the array out by hand when I already had it made.

Comment: @a_programmer I know, I just wrote it down for better testing. And tbh, your checked answer is an overkill, as shanethehat wrote in comment and I in answer, $person[$name] is best solution.

Comment: @Jurik remember to upvote him then! I have moved my wizardry section to another function - it's a preg_replace_callback. having moved it away it makes more sense to look at!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for any looping, although you should implement some kind of error checking to ensure that the name exists in the persons array.

```
function findHotty($name) {
    if (!isset($person[$name])) {
        // do something when the name doesn't exist
    }
    return $person[$name];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try below :-

```
function findHotty($billy){
   foreach ( $person as $key => $meat)
   {
          if($key=='Billy')
          {
             $meat['..'];
          }
      // wizardry 
      return onlyBilly
   }
}
```

Comment: That's overkill. What about $person['Billy'] ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to get your billy. Both functions return Billy's data or false, if there's no billy. If you've two Billy's in your array, you'll get only first one.

```
<?php
$persons = array(
  'billy' => array(
    'height' => 'tall',
    'build' => 'slim',
    'attractiveness' => 'extremely'
  },
  'carl' => array(
    'height' => 'short',
    'build' => 'chubby',
    'attractiveness' => 'neglegible'
  )
);

function findHotty($billy){
  foreach ($persons as $name => $details)
    if($name == $billy){
      return $details;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

function findHotty2($billy){
  return isset($persons[$billy]) ? $persons[$billy] : false;
};
```

Comment: Kind of a late comment but make sure to note that $persons won't be available inside those functions unless you either add `global $persons;` or pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Ahh yes, we are not in JS ;)